# Wordpress PHP dynamic sidebar generating a "1" after the code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to display widgets by permalinks...

```
            <?php        
            global $post;
            $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );
            if ( strpos( $permalink, '/one/' ) !== false || strpos( $permalink, '/one-two/' ) !== false ) {
                echo dynamic_sidebar( 'disclaimer_cop' );
            } elseif ( strpos( $permalink, '/two/' ) !== false || strpos( $permalink, '/two-one/' ) !== false ) {
                echo dynamic_sidebar( 'disclaimer' );
            } ?>
```

This code is dynamically displaying the widgets on the correct pages but when viewing the page the widget position is being followed by a random "1" in the HTML, like this.

```
<div class="widget_text disclaimer"> <div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">*Disclaimer text.</div>
1
```

Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Comment: Try removing the `echo`. Looks like you're outputting the result as well as the content.

Comment: As the previous commenter said, removing `echo` before `dynamic_sidebar(...);` will fix the issue. Also, please consider reading the documentation / doing some research before asking questions here to save everyone's time: [dynamic_sidebar() - WordPress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar).

Comment: Yea I read that and mistakenly added echo and did not even notice it was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `echo`. Looks like you're outputting the result as well as the content.

```
<?php        
  global $post;
  $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );
  if ( strpos( $permalink, '/one/' ) !== false || strpos( $permalink, '/one-two/' ) !== false ) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'disclaimer_cop' );
  } elseif ( strpos( $permalink, '/two/' ) !== false || strpos( $permalink, '/two-one/' ) !== false ) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'disclaimer' );
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are implentening on your case the code you specified. If you do it via add_shortcode() and then you call your shortcode on a widget you will just need to change the echo with a return.

Hope that helps.

Cheers!